# Regex - How to replace a string, without losing a part of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following code.

```
<a href="/29486389/Author_-_Name_of_Song.mp3/" class="popover-with-html hidden-phone">Andra - Inevitabil va fi bine.mp3</a>
```

How can I replace this string, using regex, but without losing a part from string. To looks like this

```
<a href="melodie/Author_-_Name_of_Song.mp3.html/" class="popover-with-html hidden-phone">Author - Name of Song</a>
```

I know i need to use a pattern like that:

```
$string = 'April 15, 2003';
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i';
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not simply use a DOM object? Parsing html with regex is never a clean job.

Comment: You could use the [following regex](http://regex101.com/r/eQ5bM4), note that to remove the underscore in `Author - Name of Song` is very difficult if not impossible with one regex (dynamically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### REGEX

```
<a\s+href\s*=\s*"/\d+/(.+?)_-_(.+?)\.mp3/"\s+class\s*=\s*"popover-with-html hidden-phone">.+?</a>
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit](http://www.debuggex.com/r/NQXZ7KuS-ZW0cH4r)

### PHP code

```
$pattern = '#<a\s+href="/\d+/(.+?)_-_(.+?)\.mp3/"\s+class="popover-with-html hidden-phone">.+?</a>#is';
$replacement = '<a href="melodie/$1_-_$2.mp3.html/" class="popover-with-html hidden-phone">$1 - $2</a>';

$my_clean_html_code = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $my_html_code);
```

### SAMPLE OUTPUT

- IN

```
<a href="/29486389/Author_-_Name_of_Song.mp3/" class="popover-with-html hidden-phone">Andra - Inevitabil va fi bine.mp3</a>
<a href="/29486389/Author2_-_sdfsd475.mp3/" class="popover-with-html hidden-phone">
   Andra - Inevitabil va fi bine.mp3
</a>
```

- OUT

```
<a href="melodie/Authodr_-_Name_of_Song.mp3.html/" class="popover-with-html hidden-phone">Author - Name_of_Song</a>
<a href="melodie/Author2_-_sdfsd475.mp3.html/" class="popover-with-html hidden-phone">Author2 - sdfsd475</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but if the name of song/author contains dots, the script doesn't work well anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to have underscores ('_') in the song/author?